# can't access Objective C class from swift controller code

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I am getting an Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_Intro at link time when trying to build.

I can access the class Intro inside a swift file in Xcode using Xcode's intellisense, but it doesn't seem to recognize it at build time. Can someone with more experience with swift and Xcode give me a hand.

```
class OldLoginViewController: BaseViewController {

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(OldLoginViewController.goIntro), name: NSNotification.Name("ROOTGOINTRO"), object: nil)
     
        ClsUtil.skip(toViewController: self.navigationController!, viewControllerName: "Intro", isViewDidLoad: true)
    }
    
    
    var style : UIStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.default;
    

    @objc
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let intro = Intro()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(intro, animated:false)

    }
```

Obj C code:

```
#import "BaseViewController.h"

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Intro : BaseViewController

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

Bridging header:

```
#ifndef ObjectiveCBridgingHeader_h
#define ObjectiveCBridgingHeader_h

#import "Base/Util/ClsUtil.h"
#import "Base/ViewController/BaseViewController.h"
#import "Intro/Intro.h"

#endif /* ObjectiveCBridgingHeader_h */
```

builds fine and accesses ClsUtil fine without the code involving intro, so I assume that the bridging header is set up correctly in project settings

ps - forgive the noobness. 4th day of iOS. Prior developer left and we don't have a developer to take care of iOS related issues or finish porting the prior app. I wanted to switch to using swift instead of obj c cause it looks cleaner/will give access to the latest tools.

Answer (score 1):

figured it out. It's because when I copy over folders from OS X finder, the files are not added to the "Compile Sources" section of the Build Phases Tab of the project settings.

I'm still a little confused as to what the proper method of importing folders from another project is. I assume I need to use an Xcode command of some kind instead of OS X finder